# I want to display the results from other applications(LabVIEW) in the CMD window

Tags: python, cmd

I am programming python code in LabVIEW now. I want to display my results in CMD console, but I don't know how to connect them to cmd console. My bielf code is as follows.

```
import os
os.system("start /wait cmd")
print("I want to display my results to the CMD window")
```

This ensures that only the `cmd` window appears and no print function results appear. Help me

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of programs. Console and graphical. The difference is a flag in the file header. If set as non graphical it will open with an automatic console unless it's parent program is also non graphical then it will inherit it's parent's console. If set as graphical absolutely nothing special happens.

Any program can show windows and any program can start a new console or attach to any existing console.

Your question is a bit weird. CMD is a console program. There is nothing special about it. You don't need CMD to run in a console.

So it depends on how you compile. With a graphical interpreter or a console interpreter.

However you are starting CMD disconnected from your program, which it would be if your program isn't a console program anyway, by using the `START` command which starts programs in **unusual ways**.

See `start /?`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/character-mode-applications.

PS You write to a console not to CMD.